# I cannot find the wordpress.scss file that my live site is pulling from

Tags: php, css

When I push my localhost to my live site some of my styling disappears. when I inspect the webpage it is pulling from my wordpress.scss file. I edit that file and make adjustments, but none of the adjustments work. I am stuck, and don't know where to go from here... please help.

Comment: SCSS files don't get loaded by the browser, they need to be "built" to get the CSS files

Answer (score 0):

Your browser loads `css` file and sourcemap which has links to `.scss` file which gets compiled into css.

In your theme there should be a gulp or webpack script which is used to compile scss to css file.

If you are not familiar with scss->css compilation or you can't find `package.json` and `webpack.config.js` or `gulpfile.js` files inside your theme's directory you can either look for compiled `css` file which gets actually loaded and it's usually minified to make edits. You can just override styles with yours in wordpress admin panel `Appearance -> Customize -> Additional CSS`.

If you'll find `package.json` in  your theme's directory, you can run `npm install` command in console to install dependencies and inside `package.json` there can be a `scripts` section with build commands which you can use like `npm run-script build` to build `css` from `scss` files.

Again what I've explained is just general approach without knowing neither what theme you are using nor if this theme has those build tools used.

Important thing -> after you'll make changes to css (or scss and rebuild css) and upload it to server don't forget to `CMD+R` `Ctrl+F5` to make sure your browser will load fresh updated css.

If you use git push to deploy to live site -> make sure you've added and committed all theme's files, including css which is built from scss, so they got loaded to live site when you push those changes.

Comment: That totally worked! Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @Michael you can mark answer as accepted if it is. happy to help :) !